# Largest prime factor function works too slow

Tags: javascript, function, primes

I have written the function which finds largest prime factor of some number. This function works but the problem is that it is too slow. e.g when I enter  600851475143 as a parameter, the process of finding largest prime factor lasts too long. How can I modify it so that it works faster?
Here is my code:

```
class test {

static addArray(someArray, member) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= someArray.length; i++) {
        if (i == someArray.length) {
            someArray[i] = member;
            return someArray;
        }
    }
}
static someLength(someArray) {
    var i = 0;
    while (someArray[i] !== undefined) {
        var lastItem = i;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
static testPrime(i) {
    for (var k=2; k < i; k++) {
        if (i % k == 0) {
            return false;
        }       
    }
    return true;
}
}

var primeArray = [];
function largestPrime(n) {
    for (var i=2; i < n; i++) {
        //var k = n / i;
        if (n % i == 0 && test.testPrime(i) == true) {  
            test.addArray(primeArray, i);
            n == n / i;
        }
    }
    return primeArray[test.someLength(primeArray) - 1];
}

document.write(largestPrime(600851475143));
```

Comment: This is a good question for code review, not for StackOverflow.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChrisSharp it works faster for relatively smaller numbers, I've looked through the code and I think there is no extra curly brace. The last one belongs to _class_

Answer (score 1):

Alright, before we go into that, let's get a little bit of theory sorted. The way you measure the time a particular piece of code takes to run is, mathematically, denoted by the `O(n)` notation (big-o notation) where `n` is the size of the input.

Your test prime function is of something called `linear complexity` meaning that it'll become linearly slow as the size of `n` (in this case, your number input) gets large.

For the number `15`, the execution context is as follows:

```
15 % 2 == 0 (FALSE)
15 % 3 == 0 (TRUE)
...
15 % 14 == 0 (FALSE)
```

This means that for the number `100`, there will be 98 (2 - 99) steps. And this will grow with time. Let's take your number into consideration: `600851475143`. The program will execute `600851475143`; the `for-loop` will get triggered `600,851,475,141` times.

Now, let's consider a clock cycle. Say each instruction takes `1 clock cycle`, and a dumbed down version of your loop takes 2, the number `600851475143` will execute `1,201,702,950,286` times. Consider each clock cycle takes `0.0000000625` seconds (for a 16-MHz platform such as the [Arduino](https://arduino.cc)), the time taken by that code alone is:

```
0.0000000625 * 1201702950286 = ~75,106 seconds
```

Or around `20 hours`.

You see where I am going with this.

Your best best to get this program to work faster is to use a [probabilistic test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests) and confirm your findings using this number (or a BigInteger variant thereof).

---

Your approach is more linear, in the sense that the number of iterations for the `for-loop` to check for primality increases with an increasing number. You can plot the CPU cycle time along with the number and you'll realize that this is a rather inefficient way to do this.

I have discrete mathematics at my Uni, so just a word of warning - primality tests and their variants get really messy as you get into the utopia of faster and faster tests. It's a path filled with thorns of mathematics and you should have a seat belt while riding through the jungle! ;)

If you need more information on this, I would be glad to assist! I hope this helped! :)

Comment: This is an absolutely excellent answer. [Here's a link to a great beginners guide to understanding big-o notation](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/), as I'm aware the syntax can be a little odd to approach at first.

Comment: The moment you step into algorithms, you *have* to bow down to CLRS. xD